# Does anybody know which tools allow to get (pseudo) code from a Moscow ML executable?

Tags: binary-analysis, decompilation, byte-code

I've decompiled **Win32** executable that is the result of compilation of a program written in Moscow ML language.

The resulting listing contains standard **C** `main` function that contains the call to `caml_main` that (as I understand) calls bytecode interpreter which interprets the bytecode containing in the executable.

So my questions are:

1. How to extract the bytecode without a lots of manual work?
2. How to decompile the Moscow ML bytecode?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to extract the bytecode without a lots of manual work

As per https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/runtime/main.c#L62, the last 20 bytes of the EXE make up an `exec_trailer` structure:

```
static int read_trailer(int fd, struct exec_trailer * trail)
{
  unsigned char buffer[TRAILER_SIZE];

  lseek(fd, (long) -TRAILER_SIZE, 2);
  if (read(fd, (char*)buffer, TRAILER_SIZE) < TRAILER_SIZE) 
    return TRUNCATED_FILE;
  trail->code_size = read_size(buffer);
  trail->data_size = read_size(buffer+4);
  trail->symbol_size = read_size(buffer+8);
  trail->debug_size = read_size(buffer+12);
  trail->magic = read_size(buffer+16);
  if (trail->magic == EXEC_MAGIC) return 0; else return BAD_MAGIC_NUM;
}
```

And as per https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/runtime/main.c#L229, the bytecode begins at `(20 + trail.code_size + trail.data_size + trail.symbol_size + trail.debug_size)` bytes before the end of the file.

> 2. How to decompile the Moscow ML bytecode?

The bytecode interpreter is defined here: https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/runtime/interp.c#L87

However, even if you were to leverage the parser in that interpreter, the best you'd get is an intermediate representation of the code (consisting of the instructions in https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/runtime/instruct.h), not the decompiled ML code itself.

If you want to convert the intermediate instructions to an actual decompilation, that question would probably be better asked at https://stackoverflow.com/.